# Pandas - creating new column based on if condition

Tags: pandas, if-statement, data-cleaning

I have the following dataframe and I want to create a column `'poster'` that shows the user if `comment_id != np.nan` and is `np.nan` if otherwise.

I have tried to do this with an if-statement in a for loop but instead of only getting the user name in the `'poster'` column if there is an integer in the comment_id column, I get the user name in the 'poster' column for both integers and `np.nan` in the `'comment_id'` column. There is probably only a small thing that is wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

```
d = {'comment_id':[1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3],
     'user': ["Bob", "Ben", "Ben", "Charly", "Steve", "Tracy"]}

toydf = pd.DataFrame(d)

toydf['poster'] = np.nan

for n in toydf['comment_id']:
    if n != np.nan:
        toydf['poster']=toydf['user']
    else:
        toydf['poster']= np.nan
```

Comment: nothing equals `np.nan` , `np.nan==np.nan` would return `False`

Comment: Yeah, I see it now, how would you write that condition that something equals np.nan though?

Comment: pandas has an `isna`/`isnull` builtin as mentioned in an answer below

Comment: @rtzu Hello mate, if any of the answers helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/694919). This is important so that other users with the same problem can see that it has already been solved

Comment: @Terry sorry about that! Is it possible to accept two answers if they both helped?

Comment: Only one can be accepted. What was the best answer is up to you (the quickest, the easiest to understand, it fits best with other dependencies in project). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loc` rows where **comment_id** is not null and then save the **user** values

```
toydf.loc[toydf['comment_id'].notna(), 'poster'] = toydf['user']
#output
    comment_id  user    poster
0   1.0         Bob     Bob
1   NaN         Ben     NaN
2   2.0         Ben     Ben
3   NaN         Charly  NaN
4   NaN         Steve   NaN
5   3.0         Tracy   Tracy
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job too!

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `mask` with condition `isna`

```
df['New'] = df.user.mask(df.comment_id.isna())
df
Out[145]: 
   comment_id    user    New
0         1.0     Bob    Bob
1         NaN     Ben    NaN
2         2.0     Ben    Ben
3         NaN  Charly    NaN
4         NaN   Steve    NaN
5         3.0   Tracy  Tracy
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps!